# Google Analytics email when X happens?

Tags: google-analytics

If i get more than X visitors on Google Analytics i'd like to be emailed. Is there any way i can ask GA to do this? I found how to do it for custom reports but it seems like emailing daily reports. I only want to be emailed when a specific event happens http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom inteligence alert.

Go to Home > Inteligence Events > Overview.

From there click on the tab custom alerts and then click on Manage Custom Alerts.

eg:

[image]